# Oracle - Can A Bind Variable Be Put In In() Clause If The Variable Can Be Empty

Tags: oracle, where-clause

In `Oracle`, can a bind variable be put in `IN()` clause if it can be empty? Asking because in the SQL if Oracle see `IN()` without any data in it, it shows error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression.
```

Edit: Failed to mention that no PL/SQL can be used...

Edit2: Also failed to mention that the variable is either in format 1,2,3 or empty string. The empty string cannot be replaced with NULL.

Comment: Wouldn't it see `IN(null)`?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: var can only be 1,2,3 for example or nothing (not null) select * from table where code in (nvl(,null)) would result in error

Comment: Define 'nothing' - why isn't that `null`? Empty string (`''`) and `null` are the same thing in Oracle. If you have a bind varible in the query then it won't disappear. Maybe you should show your code so we can see what you really mean, and any errors you've got so far.

Comment: There's a PHP code which replaces the variable with either 1,2,3 or empty string which is not surrounded by quotes (neither null, nor empty string surrounded by quotes ''). This makes it impossible I guess. Thanks for the efforts anyway and sorry for not explaining it good enough.

Comment: So it isn't actually a bind variable at all? If that's the case then can the PHP just remove the whole clause from the query instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working:

```
declare

   l_statement varchar2(32767);

begin
   l_statement := 'select * from user_tables where table_name in (:a)';

   execute immediate l_statement
      using '';

end;
```

Comment: That's not an empty list, it's a list containing an empty string.

Comment: Empty string and null are the same thing in Oracle

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, it will be syntactically correct. 
I hope you are aware that NULL is not equal to anything even to NULL (so NULL=NULL is not TRUE but NULL), it can cause unexpected results in your query, so consider using NVL function if it doesn't affect performance